# DAG, finding edges for subset of vertices

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG G=(V,E), it is adjacency list representation. I am trying to compress it according to some parameters that are attached to vertices.

Now I have a graph G=(V,E) and a list containing subset of V.

Any idea how can I efficiently find edges for subset vertices from original graph?

I need to connect the subset using the original graph.

Look at this graph

{9: [10], 7: [9], 8: [9], 6: [7], 3: [8], 2: [3, 4], 5: [4, 6], 4: [7], 1: [2]}

Now if I take the subset [1,4,7]

How do find connections for subset? please see the transitive closure as an issue. I need to find all edges but not the duplicates in transitive closure.

Answer (score 0):

Put the subset (let's call it *S*) into a hashtable. Then walk through the adjacency list and for every edge look whether its first vertex is in the hashtable. This way you get all the edges you want in *O*(|*S*| + |*E*|).

Comment: the problem is a little complicated. I should have explained more. I need to connect the subset by finding edges from original graph.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be to find the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the original graph (using [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)) and then using that to add the edges to the resulting graph.

By finding the transitive closure, you have an adjacency matrix where matrix[x][y] is true whenever there is any path (direct or indirect) between vertices x and y in the original graph. Using that, you can simply add the edges (a,b) for each pair of vertices a and b in the subset graph iff matrix[a][b] is true (i.e. there was a path from a to b in the original graph).

This would end up adding more edges than strictly necessary, but it would give you an accurate subset graph.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to utilize some algorithm to get the transitive closure. From your example it seems that the graph is very sparse, so instead of Floyd-Warshall, use [Johnson's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm). Johnson's Algo requires O((V^2)*log V + VE) which is less that that of Floyd-Warshall's O(V^3) for sparse graphs. Note that this difference is appreciable only if you have a large sparse graph.

Now add the edges of the form < x,y> for each pair of vertices in the subset-graph if x is reachable from y (which will be given by Johnson's Algo).

Answer (score 0):

If your subset is S, you can do |S| [depth-first searches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (or [breadth-first searches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) to determine the edges in your subset graph.  Each search is *O(V+E)*, so that's *O(V^2+VE)* or better *O(S(V+E))*, if S is small.  You then might want to use a [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) to remove unnecessary edges.

If your graph is not completely acyclic, it will almost certainly help to coalesce [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) first.  It is cheap to do and can reduce the work required substantially.

Comment: This is my current implementation. I am rendering multiple graphs on browser and it's slow. I think I should stop my bfs when I have found all subset nodes, this may improve time a little bit.